# beta differs from overall subgroup

Tags: regression

My plain regression looks as follows:

tendaystockreturn = alpha + beta * dummy variable that takes a value of 1 in case a director purchases shares

Now I want to test whether a subgroup of directors will have a higher beta. In other words,
I want to know whether the beta of a subgroup differs from the beta of the overall group.

The overall director dummy variable has 52 out of 267 obseverations where it takes a value of 1.
The subgroup director dummy variable has 17 out of 267 observation where it takes a value of 1.

How should I put this in the regression? Should I make an interaction of both dummy variables or not? Or should I run both regression separately and then compare?

Answer (score 3):

There's not enough information in your question to clearly see what you're doing (you should edit to explain more clearly what your data - including the response variable - and model consist of), but it's still possible to give some important advice.

If you compare a subgroup with the overall (which includes the subgroup) you will induce dependence that you can easily avoid.

Logically, comparing the subgroup with everything but the subgroup yields *exactly* the same information as comparing overall, but makes for a simpler, more standard analysis.

(Consider: if A is the same as B, then A is the same as A&B combined.)

So you should instead compare the subgroup with the remainder.