# Subgroups comparison

Tags: subset

I have to compare two subgroups from the same population.
The two groups have partially the same records, so they are overlapping subsets of the same dataset.
Can I consider them as two independent groups and consequentially run analyses for independent groups?

Comment: What does "partially the same records" mean?

Comment: Means like group A=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), group B=c(2,5,6,7,9). Group B is included in group A. Group A is the population of interest, group B is the population with less than 65yrs. I would like to compare the outcome (illness) between the complete population and the younger population. Thank you

Comment: So you'd like to compare group A and group B means while keeping group B as subgroup of group A? I haven't done this myself but there are several answers regarding this issue, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134627/compare-means-of-group-with-a-mean-of-a-subgroup) , [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30562/how-to-test-whether-subgroup-mean-differs-from-overall-group-that-includes-the) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116102/compare-group-mean-to-larger-group-of-which-it-is-part).